# What is the output and why?

Tags: java

What would the output be of these two statements. I am having trouble understanding how this works. I would say for number 1, b = 33. This is it says a=a+1 so therefor a = 33. b is equal to a, so b must also be 33? For the second one I would say b = delmar. Sort of confused, would appreciate some help, thanks.

1:

```
int a;
int b;
a = 32;
b = a;
a = a + 1;
System.out.println(b);
```

2:

```
Person a;
Person b;
a = new Person("Everett");
b = a;
a.changeName("Delmar");
System.out.println(b.getName());
```

Comment: My advice: (1) run the code and observe what happens; (2) if what happens isn't what you'd expect, step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Also, be sure to mark the most helpful answer as correct, for future readers. This is a core concept.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of a `reference` in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one, the value of `a` is *copied* to b. So the change in `a` later doesn't affect `b`.

In the second both `a` and `b` refer to the same object. So change in `a` later will reflect in `b`.

So the output will be: `32` in the first case and `Delmar` in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

Output of the first statement is 32. This is because b is not an object, so the int variable doesn't represent a pointer to an object; it represents the actual value.

The second statement will output "Delmar". This is because B and A actually point to the same object, and when you change a value in a, you implicitly change the value in b.

Answer (score 0):

In case of premetive after addition, new object is created. Hence b would point to old a which is equal to 32.

But in case of non premetive Person class both a and b are pointing to same object hence any change to object will be reflated to both refrence variable.